# Spring AOP and getting result of method

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop

I'm writing a custom metrics service using AOP. Here are my custon annotation

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface Metric {
}
```

and aspect-class:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Aspect
@Component
@Data
public class MetricAspect {

    Map<Signature, Map<Object, Counter>> metrics = new HashMap<>();

    @AfterReturning("@annotation(Metric)")
    public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
        metrics.get(signature).get("Success").increment();
    }
}
```

I have added my custom annotation on my method:

```
@Override
@Metric
public GetCMOwnerInvoiceResponseDTO getCMOwnerInvoice(GetCMOwnerInvoiceRequestDTO getCMOwnerInvoiceRequest) throws ValidationWebFault_Exception {
    GetCMOwnerInvoiceRequest request = wsConversionService.convert(getCMOwnerInvoiceRequest, GetCMOwnerInvoiceRequest.class);
    GetCMOwnerInvoiceResponse response = invoiceService.getCMOwnerInvoice(request);
    return wsConversionService.convert(response, GetCMOwnerInvoiceResponseDTO.class);
}
```

I need to add the result of the method which is an `GetCMOwnerInvoiceResponseDTO` object to my `metrics` map, instead of word "Success". Which arguments or annotation do I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `returning` attribute

```
@AfterReturning("@annotation(Metric)" , returning="returnValue")
public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object returnValue) {
```